# Gradle and Mysql in gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a test job which requires gradle to run the test as well as mysql. [This example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html#example-project)
 shows how to use mysql. The problem is the image tag in the link overrides my global image tag of gradle because of which gradle is not found. Is there a way to use multiple images in one job or any other work-around.

This is a shortened version of .gitlab-ci.yml. [This](https://gitlab.com/rahem027/preeti_bhojan_backend/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)  is the full one:

```
image: gradle:jdk11

# Disable the Gradle daemon for Continuous Integration servers as correctness
# is usually a priority over speed in CI environments. Using a fresh
# runtime for each build is more reliable since the runtime is completely
# isolated from any previous builds.

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

## build configs....
test_MariaDBImpl:
  needs:
    - build_MariaDBImpl
  stage: test
  services:
    - mysql
  image: mysql
  script:
      - echo "create user if not exists 'test'@'localhost'; grant all privileges on *.* to 'test'@'localhost'; flush privileges;" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql
      - gradle cleanTest :MariaDBImpl:test
```

**Edit 1:** One work around that I thought of was to add a `before_script` and download either gradle or mysql in it but I guess there is a better way?

**Edit 2:** Or maybe create a docker image with all three and use that one instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour with GitLab-CI. You set `image: gradle:jdk11` as default image to use for the CI job unless overridden in the job configuration like you did with `image: mysql`.

As you said you have several options here if you need both `gradle` and `mysql-client`.

- Build your own Docker image that contains both
- Remove `image: mysql`, use the default `image: gradle:jdk11` and install `mysql-client` at the beginning of your `script` block or with `before_script`. `gradle:jdk11` is based on Ubuntu so you can run: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client`
- Keep `image: mysql` and install gradle with `apt-get update && apt-get install -y gradle` (I don't recommend that, installing gradle via APT install a lot of packages and will slow your CI job down unnecessarily)
- <s>Keep `image: mysql`, add  [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) to your repository and directly call it from gitlab-ci.</s> *Edit: This is not very useful as it would also require to download the JDK to build the project. It works best if the base image already contains it.*

My preference would be to keep on using `gradle:jdk11` as base image and just install the `mysql-client` package for that specific job since your other jobs only need gradle.

Comment: The gradle wrapper is in the repository already. Do you think its worth it to install mysql each time? Building my own docker image seems much better. Thats why I am confused

Comment: P.S. I know it is the expected behavior of Gitlab-CI

Comment: If you already have gradle wrapper you can keep the `image: mysql` image for the job and invoke `./gradlew cleanTest :MariaDBImpl:test` ?

Comment: Does that mean I don't even need image:gradle? I need jdk 11 to build?

Comment: Ha yeah sorry about that. If your project is a Java project you will need to have the jdk installed on the base image making the usage of `mysql` not ideal. I'd go with installing `mysql-client` into the `gradle:jdk11` based container then.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mind adding the last comment to the answer? I think that makes a lot of sense for other newbies